# How can I randomize coordinates in javascript canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Newbie here, currently learning how to code. My teacher gave me the task of proving myself in canvas by making a smiley face on my own.
[This is the result so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7isaK.png)

Now he gave me the task of randomizing the coordinates, so that the smiley *as a whole* appears in a new place everytime (whether that happens on load or through a button is my decision).

Edit: to clarify, my problem lies more within the logic behind altering the coordinates of my canvas. I've tried to figure out how to do this, and know that I'll need `Math.random` for that.

Edit: to clarify, my problem lies more within the logic behind

My code:

```
<body onload="draw();">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>

    <script type="application/javascript">
        function draw() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var smiley = canvas.getContext("2d");

                //Face shape
                smiley.beginPath();
                smiley.arc(75, 75, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);

                //Right eye
                smiley.moveTo(65,55);
                smiley.arc(55,55,10,0, Math.PI * 2, true); 

                //Left eye
                smiley.moveTo(105,55);
                smiley.arc(95,55,10,0, Math.PI * 2, true); 

                //Mouth
                smiley.moveTo(35,75);
                smiley.arc(75, 75, 40, 0, Math.PI, false); 
                smiley.moveTo(36,81);
                smiley.lineTo(114,81);
                smiley.stroke();

                //Pupils
                smiley.beginPath(58,55);
                smiley.moveTo(58,55);
                smiley.arc(55,55,3,0, Math.PI*2,true);
                smiley.moveTo(98,55);
                smiley.arc(95,55,3,0, Math.PI*2, true);
                smiley.fill()

                //Hair
                smiley.beginPath(75,25);
                smiley.moveTo(75,25);
                smiley.lineTo(75,5);
                smiley.moveTo(79,5);
                smiley.lineTo(78,25);
                smiley.moveTo(72,25);
                smiley.lineTo(71,5);
                smiley.stroke();

                //Nose
                smiley.beginPath();
                smiley.moveTo(73,50);
                smiley.lineTo(67,67);
                smiley.lineTo(80,70);
                smiley.stroke();

                smiley.beginPath()
                smiley.moveTo(73,50);
                smiley.lineTo(63,69);
                smiley.lineTo(80,70);
                smiley.lineTo(67,67);
                smiley.lineTo(73,50);
                smiley.fill();
                smiley.endPath();
            }

    </script>
</body>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you need to use Math.random() which gives a number between 0 and 1. But you need a range between 50 and canvasWidth-50 
I expanded canvas width to demonstrate randomness more

```html
<body onload="draw();">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="450px" height="450px"></canvas>

    <script type="application/javascript">
        function draw() {
        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var x=Math.random()*(canvas.width-100)-25; //smiley's width 100 and your initial value was +75 it needed to be 100/2=50
        var y=Math.random()*(canvas.height-100)-25; //smiley's height 100 and your initial value was +75 it needed to be 100/2=50
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var smiley = canvas.getContext("2d");

                //Face shape
                smiley.beginPath();
                smiley.arc(75+x, 75+y, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);

                //Right eye
                smiley.moveTo(65+x,55+y);
                smiley.arc(55+x,55+y,10,0, Math.PI * 2, true); 

                //Left eye
                smiley.moveTo(105+x,55+y);
                smiley.arc(95+x,55+y,10,0, Math.PI * 2, true); 

                //Mouth
                smiley.moveTo(35+x,75+y);
                smiley.arc(75+x, 75+y, 40, 0, Math.PI, false); 
                smiley.moveTo(36+x,81+y);
                smiley.lineTo(114+x,81+y);
                smiley.stroke();

                //Pupils
                smiley.beginPath(58+x,55+y);
                smiley.moveTo(58+x,55+y);
                smiley.arc(55+x,55+y,3,0, Math.PI*2,true);
                smiley.moveTo(98+x,55+y);
                smiley.arc(95+x,55+y,3,0, Math.PI*2, true);
                smiley.fill()

                //Hair
                smiley.beginPath(75+x,25+y);
                smiley.moveTo(75+x,25+y);
                smiley.lineTo(75+x,5+y);
                smiley.moveTo(79+x,5+y);
                smiley.lineTo(78+x,25+y);
                smiley.moveTo(72+x,25+y);
                smiley.lineTo(71+x,5+y);
                smiley.stroke();

                //Nose
                smiley.beginPath();
                smiley.moveTo(73+x,50+y);
                smiley.lineTo(67+x,67+y);
                smiley.lineTo(80+x,70+y);
                smiley.stroke();

                smiley.moveTo(73+x,50+y);
                smiley.lineTo(63+x,69+y);
                smiley.lineTo(80+x,70+y);
                smiley.lineTo(67+x,67+y);
                smiley.lineTo(73+x,50+y);
                smiley.fill();
            }

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, that explained it very well. I thought I need a whole new function that would actually substract the coordinates, but this is so much easier! But could you explain why it is ```(canvas.width-100)-25```?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getRandom(from, to) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * to) + from
}

function normalise(px, shift) {
  return px - 75 + shift // moving it to 0 and then shifting it to anywhere
}


function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var smiley = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const [startx, starty] = [getRandom(75, 100), getRandom(75, 100)];
  console.log(startx, starty);


  //Face shape
  smiley.beginPath();
  smiley.arc(normalise(75, startx), normalise(75, starty), 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);

  //Right eye
  smiley.moveTo(normalise(65, startx), normalise(55, starty));
  smiley.arc(normalise(55, startx), normalise(55, starty), 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);

  //Left eye
  smiley.moveTo(normalise(105, startx), normalise(55, starty));
  smiley.arc(normalise(95, startx), normalise(55, starty), 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);

  //Mouth
  smiley.moveTo(normalise(35, startx), normalise(75, starty));
  smiley.arc(normalise(75, startx), normalise(75, starty), 40, 0, Math.PI, false);
  smiley.moveTo(normalise(36, startx), normalise(81, starty));
  smiley.lineTo(normalise(114, startx), normalise(81, starty));
  smiley.stroke();

  //Pupils
  smiley.beginPath(normalise(58, startx), normalise(55, starty));
  smiley.moveTo(normalise(58, startx), normalise(55, starty));
  smiley.arc(normalise(55, startx), normalise(55, starty), 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  smiley.moveTo(normalise(98, startx), normalise(55, starty));
  smiley.arc(normalise(95, startx), normalise(55, starty), 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  smiley.fill()

  //Hair
  smiley.beginPath(normalise(75, startx), normalise(25, starty));
  smiley.moveTo(normalise(75, startx), normalise(25, starty));
  smiley.lineTo(normalise(75, startx), normalise(5, starty));
  smiley.moveTo(normalise(79, startx), normalise(5, starty));
  smiley.lineTo(normalise(78, startx), normalise(25, starty));
  smiley.moveTo(normalise(72, startx), normalise(25, starty));
  smiley.lineTo(normalise(71, startx), normalise(5, starty));
  smiley.stroke();

  //Nose
  smiley.beginPath();
  smiley.moveTo(normalise(73, startx), normalise(50, starty));
  smiley.lineTo(normalise(67, startx), normalise(67, starty));
  smiley.lineTo(normalise(80, startx), normalise(70, starty));
  smiley.stroke();

  smiley.beginPath()
  smiley.moveTo(normalise(73, startx), normalise(50, starty));
  smiley.lineTo(normalise(63, startx), normalise(69, starty));
  smiley.lineTo(normalise(80, startx), normalise(70, starty));
  smiley.lineTo(normalise(67, startx), normalise(67, starty));
  smiley.lineTo(normalise(73, startx), normalise(50, starty));
  smiley.fill();
  // smiley.endPath();
}
```